# What will we use Theory Attribute for?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit

I discovered `[Theory]` and `[Datapoint]` attributes in NUnit. I am not very sure about how should I use these. I think they can be used for data-driven testing and this has got me interested. There aren't many resources available on the same. Can someone explain to me how to use them or point me to resources? Thanks.

Comment: Have you used theories after all? I can see some very close similarities with Code Contracts which actually do a similar thing. They provide a theory over input data. It's just that it's in runnable code and not tests.

Comment: duplicate (or similar) question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961786/theory-vs-test-nunit

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the online NUnit docs? There's an example here that shows you how you can use the [Theory] and [Datapoint] attributes:

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=theory&r=2.5.3

Comment: Well... For what it's worth, I really can't consider this valuable documentation of `TheoryAttribute`. It just outlines some info, but no actual execution...

Answer (score 0):

> A Theory is a special type of test, used to verify a general statement
>   about the system under development. Normal tests are example-based.
>   That is, the developer supplies one or more examples of inputs and
>   expected outputs either within the code of the test or - in the case
>   of Parametrized Tests - as arguments to the test method. A theory, on
>   the other hand, makes a general statement that all of its assertions
>   will pass for all arguments satisfying certain assumptions.
>
> Theories are implemented in `NUnit` as methods within a `TestFixture`,
>   which are annotated with the `TheoryAttribute` (`[Theory]`). Theory
>   methods must always have arguments and therefore appears quite similar
>   to Parameterized Tests at first glance. However, a Theory incorporates
>   additional data sources for its arguments and allows special
>   processing for assumptions about that data. The key difference,
>   though, is that theories make general statements and are more than
>   just a set of examples.
>
> Data for Theories
>
> The primary source of data for a Theory is the Datapoint or Datapoints
>   attribute. NUnit will use any fields of the required types, which are
>   annotated with one of these attributes, to provide data for each
>   parameter of the Theory. NUnit assembles the values for individual
>   arguments combinatorially to provide test cases for the theory.
>
> In addition to the Datapoint and Datapoints attributes, it is possible
>   to use any of the approaches for supplying data that are recognized on
>   normal parameterized tests. We suggest that this capability not be
>   overused, since it runs counter to the distinction between a test
>   based on examples and a theory. However, it may be useful in order to
>   guarantee that a specific test case is included.
>
> Assumptions
>
> The theory itself is responsible for ensuring that all data supplied
>   meets its assumptions. It does this by use of the `Assume.That(...)`
>   construct, which works just like `Assert.That(...)` but does not cause
>   a failure. If the assumption is not satisfied for a particular test
>   case, that case returns an Inconclusive result, rather than a Success
>   or Failure.
>
> The overall result of executing a Theory over a set of test cases is
>   determined as follows:
>
> If the assumptions are violated for all test cases, then the Theory
>   itself is marked as a failure.     If any Assertion fails, the Theory
>   itself fails.     If at least some cases pass the stated assumptions,
>   and there are no assertion failures or exceptions, then the Theory
>   passes.
>
> Example:
>
> In the following example, the theory `SquareRootDefinition` verifies
>   that the implementation of square root satisies the following
>   definition:
>
> "Given a non-negative number, the square root of that number is always
>   non-negative and, when multiplied by itself, gives the original
>   number."
>
> ```
> public class SqrtTests
> {
>     [Datapoint]
>     public double zero = 0;
>
>     [Datapoint]
>     public double positive = 1;
>
>     [Datapoint]
>     public double negative = -1;
>
>     [Datapoint]
>     public double max = double.MaxValue;
>
>     [Datapoint]
>     public double infinity = double.PositiveInfinity;
>
>     [Theory]
>     public void SquareRootDefinition(double num)
>     {
>         Assume.That(num >= 0.0 && num < double.MaxValue);
>
>         double sqrt = Math.Sqrt(num);
>
>         Assert.That(sqrt >= 0.0);
>         Assert.That(sqrt * sqrt, Is.EqualTo(num).Within(0.000001));
>     }
> }
> ```

[Taken from](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=theory&r=2.5.3)