# jUnit ignore @Test methods from base class

Tags: java, inheritance, junit

Let's say I have a test class called `testFixtureA` with several methods `testA`, `testB`, `testC`, etc, each with `@Test` annotation.

Let's now say I subclass `testFixtureA` into class called `testFixtureAB` and I don't overwrite anything. `testFixtureAB` is empty as for now.

When I run tests from `testFixtureAB`, methods `testA`, `testB` and `testC` are executed by test runner because test runner doesn't distinguish between test methods from class and baseclass.

How can I force test runner to leave out tests from baseclass?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Restructure your test classes.

- If you don't want to use the tests from the baseclass, then don't extend it
- If you need other functionality from the base class, split that class in two - the tests, and the other functionality

Comment: This is unhelpful for the reason that @martosoler points out in the answer below - there are obvious cases (in my situation, Selenium tests against different browsers) where this is very bad advice. You *want* the same behaviour sometimes; only the setup of your "SUT" variable(s) differs between subclasses.

Comment: @MikeBurton - Actually, this is good advice, although it may not be obvious what Bozho is suggesting.

What you need to do is *refactor* your base class, extracting the code that should be reused into a new, (abstract) proto-base class.  Your new test class would then extend the proto-base class rather than what we were calling the base class.  This would be a good example of following the LSP and the general rule that you should never override concrete implementations.

If you don't mind breaking those rules, you can go with my recommendation below.

Comment: I don't actually know why I was objecting to this back in July. This is exactly the solution I landed on eventually. Although it feels at this point like there's an AOP solution that would solve my specific problem better. I'm not ambitious enough to solve it at the moment, however.

Answer (score 28):

> and I don't overwrite anything.
>   testFixtureAB is empty as for now

There's your answer. If you want to not run testB from the main class, overrride it:

```
public class testFixtureAB extends testFixtureA {
   @Override
   public void testB() {}
}
```

Comment: to clarify for others since I didn't understand this answer when I first saw it, let's say you have method `testB` in base class annotated with @Test, and you don't want `testB` test to run in your subclass, then go to subclass, override this `testB` method, then this test will no longer run in your subclass

Answer (score 12):

ignoring the whole base class:

```
@Ignore
class BaseClass {
   // ...
}
```

[check out this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837484/junit-theory-for-hashcode-equals-contract)

Comment: This will ignore the base class everywhere, making it basically useless.

Comment: Make the base class abstract?

Answer (score 10):

It's quite easy to achieve implementing some few classes:

- Create your own `TestRunner`
- Create an annotation like `@IgnoreInheritedTests`
- Create a class that extends `org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter`

On the filter class:

```
public class InheritedTestsFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldRun(Description description) {
        Class<?> clazz = description.getTestClass();
        String methodName = description.getMethodName();
        if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(IgnoreInheritedTests.class)) {
            try {
                return clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName) != null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String describe() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

on your custom runner:

```
 /**
 * @param klass
 * @throws InitializationError
 * @since
 */
public CustomBaseRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
    super(klass);
    try {
        this.filter(new InheritedTestsFilter());
    } catch (NoTestsRemainException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("class should contain at least one runnable test", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Junit 5, you can make base class as abstract and extends it with a concrete class.

When you run the abstract in your IDE, your subclass will  get executed instead.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest JUnit you can use the @Rule annotation on the subclass to inspect the test name and intercept the test run to ignore the test dynamically. But I would suggest that @Bozho's idea is the better one - the fact that you need to do this indicates a bigger problem that probably shows inheritance is not the right solution here.

Answer (score 1):

I know, it's not the answer...

Consider the reason why you extend concrete test classes. You do duplicate test methods that way.

If you share code between tests then consider writing base test classes with [helper and fixture setup methods](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fresh%20Fixture%20Setup.html) or [test helper class](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Helper.html).

If for running tests then try organizing tests with suites and [categories](http://saffgreenbar.blogspot.com/2009/11/heres-test-code-snippet-public.html).

Answer (score 1):

What if you want to execute the same test for different configurations of the same test suite?

For example, let's say you have Class A with test1, test2 and test3 methods that hit an embedded database then you want to create separated "setUp" and "tearDown" for every embedded vendor (H2, HyperSQL, etc) but runs the same testing for each one.

I would like to extend a class that contain those test methods and configure it in a subclass. My problem is that the super class SHOULD NOT be considered as eligible for the test runner. The problem arises when the test runner executes the super class and given that don't found the corresponding setup and teardown methods, it crashs :(

Answer (score 0):

In the base test class' @Test methods:

```
assumeTrue(getClass().equals(BaseClassTest.class));
```

It will ignore those in the subclass tests but not completely leave them out.

Answer (score 0):

If for any reason you need two JUnit classes for same functionality, the best approach for me is:

- put the common code in a parent class `TestFixture` with only constants and mocked services.
- create two subclasses: `TestFixtureA` and `TestFixtureB`

This way you will not have duplicated code, nor double runs.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue where I had a generic abstract base class TestBase and 2 subclasses TestA, TestB that extended the base class. I wanted all tests from TestBase to run for TestA but to skip some for TestB. You can use the JUnit annotations `Nested` and `Disabled` to group tests in the base class into categories and then enable a full disable of that entire category of tests.

```
public class TestB extends TestBase {

  // disable entire suite of inherited tests
  // from the nested class declared on the parent
  @Nested
  @Disabled
  public class ComponentCTests {}

}

public abstract class TestBase {

  @Nested
  public class ComponentCTests {
     @Test
     public void testSomething() {
      // test something
      }
  }
}
```