# Junit running subclass invokes superclass testcases

Tags: java, junit

Say there're 2 JUnit classes, bigTest and smallTest. smallTest is the subclass of bigTest, and both contain some tests. When trying to run smallTest in Eclipse as JUnit testing, the testcases in both classes are run, instead of just the testcases in smallTest being run. Why is this so? Is there a way to only run smallTest's testcases without invoking bigTest's testcases?

Comment: Several alternative answers are available on a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207070/junit-ignore-test-methods-from-base-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you derive one test from the other (which I consider a bad practise) then the derived class inherits all methods.
The JunitRunner searches all methods which starts with "test", and finds of course the methods from parent and sub class.

Comment: Then, is there a way I could make both tests run independently while sharing some common methods? For example 2 tests that test different things but use a common set of API? thanks

Comment: Create an additonal helper Class, called Tools.java, and put the shared code, there. But dont call that Helpclass with a "Test.java" at the end

Comment: you can put common code in an abstract base test case class.

Comment: @RayTayek ok if it as abstract yes. I had bad experience if it now abstract, then the unit runner searche test cases, does not find any, and outputs an error

Answer (score 1):

Your sub class inherits the test methods from the parent so all the tests will be run. Just reverse where you have the methods (make smallTest the base class and bigTest the sub-class) then when you run small test, only its methods will execute.