# How to notify JUnit of exceptions generated in @DataPoints annotated methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I have implemented a generic test for the `hashCode` and `equals` methods using JUnit's experimental `@Theory` annotation. The test case class itself is based on [dfa's version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/837484/610108).

However, when I was trying to test the `java.net.InetAddress` class, I have come across a peculiar problem if the method that supplies the data points contains code that throws an exception (in this case an `UnknownHostException`):

So I tried two alternatives that both led to the same unsatisfactory result:

1. Declare the method as throwing the appropriate exception:

   ```
   @DataPoints
   public static InetAddress[] declareException() throws UnknownHostException {
       return new InetAddress[] {
           InetAddress.getByName("not a valid internet address")
       };
   }
   ```
2. Explicitly catch the exception and re-throw as an `AssertionError`:

   ```
   @DataPoints
   public static InetAddress[] rethrowAsAssertionError() {
       try {
           return new InetAddress[] {
               InetAddress.getByName("not a valid internet address")
           };
       } catch(UnknownHostException ex) {
           throw new AssertionError(ex);
       }
   }
   ```

In both cases, an `AssertionError` is thrown with the unhelpful message *"Never found parameters that satisfied method assumptions.  Violated assumptions: []"*, which is the same as not having a `@DataPoints` annotated method in the first place.

Does anyone know if there is a way to propagate the exception to JUnit (and, ultimately, the user) or is this a bug in JUnit?

Comment: Why is your data point generator throwing an exception? Shouldn't you just write it in a way that valid data will always be generated?

Comment: Ideally, yes, but (a) nobody is perfect, so I don't want to just swallow the checked `UnknownHostException`, and (b) I can think of use cases (e.g. using a live database/webserver ...) that can throw exceptions even on correct code. So a mechanism is needed to inform the user that the exception has occurred.

Comment: (a) So it takes a little longer to find the bug in your test, it still should be fixed. (b) That sounds like you are not talking about testing anymore. At best, you are doing integration testing instead of unit testing. But if that is the case, then I think you are not using `@DataPoints` the way it was intended. The data should be values the should produce deterministic results, not a function of the code you are testing.

Comment: @unholysampler re (b) I could possibly conceive of a scenario in which a database would be supplying the test data, but I'd be reaching, and my particular case involves scenario (a). Yes, the bug should be fixed, I am not advocating it shouldn't, but the testing code and tools should also make that as easy as possible. Matthew's answer provides exactly that. It does alert me to the bug in my data point generator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known problem [137: Exceptions hidden in DataPoints methods](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/issues/137).

The workaround is to create your data points in a @BeforeClass, and then just use it from the DataPoints:

```
private static InetAddress[] datapoints;

@BeforeClass
public static void generateData() throws UnknownHostException {
  // do all the work of generating the datapoints
  datapoints = new InetAddress[] {
    InetAddress.getByName("not a valid internet address")
  };
}

@DataPoints
public static InetAddress[] data() {
  return datapoints;
}
```

and this should work.

There is a pending pull request [328: @DataPoints-related fixes](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/pull/328), but it's currently still under discussion, it has not yet been accepted.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Also, +1 for pointing out it's a known issue with a pending resolution.